# Xcode Invalid Toolchain. After installing Xcode 11 Beta

Tags: ios, xcode

After submitting a build to App Store for review, Apple said:

> ITMS-90111: Invalid Toolchain - Your app was built with a beta version
>   of Xcode or SDK. Apps submitted to the App Store must be built with
>   the GM version of Xcode 9 and the SDK for iOS 11, tvOS 11, watchOS 4,
>   or macOS 10.13 or later.

I'm guessing this may or may not be affected by installing Xcode 11 Beta.
I'm using an Xcode downloaded directly from the App Store. To be more specific, the version is a GM one. `Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)`.

REFERENCE: https://xcodereleases.com/

I also have tried already the `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`, and re-uloaded a new build, only to get the same error from Apple.

What am I missing here?